# Bootstrap 3.0 Media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm working on a small project based on Boostrap 3 (html5boilerplate custom build) and trying to use the "official" media queries [in the boostrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries):

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, up to 480px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg) { ... }
```

For some reason the media queries doesn't seem to exist (@screen-sm, screen-md, screen-lg), I'm searching for this in the bootstrap files but can't find any references.

My example code (main.css):

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm) {

    .header-btn {display: none;}

}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md) {

    .slogan {display: none;}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg) {}
```

Basically what happening is... nothing!

I get those errors in Chrome:
http://i.solidfiles.net/0d0ce2d2a7.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bootstrap documentation is a little unclear.

Using these `@...` parameters for min-width is in fact *less* syntax, not *CSS*.

You should [use the customize utility in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics) (see *Media queries breakpoints*) to set up what you want these `screen-xxx` parameters to be (e.g. set screen-sm to be 768px).

And then when click the Compile button in the bottom, the less code is compiled to CSS. this compilation will replace all occurrences of @screen-sm with 768px, and the same for the other parameters.

Comment: But when i am calling in LESS "@media (min-width: @screen-sm) { ... }" it shows me "Unrecognized input". I am using SimpleLESS. I find that @screen-sm have value in bootstrap.less 768px. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: @edonbajrami, sorry - don't know anything about SimpleLESS. I recommend creating a brand new question for this - someone should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

@adonbajrami: I think you need to add `@import "myStyle.less"` in the bottom of the `bootstrap.less` file.

The file `bootstrap.less` imports `variables.less`. 
Including your file in the same parent file will give your file `myStyle.less` access to the variables declared in variables.less.

(Sorry for not commenting in place, but I'm not yet able to.)