# Adjust table cells in Bootstrap to content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table using **Bootstrap**, where the content of each table cell is a button. I want the width of each cell to be the width of the button plus margin. I tried resizing using `<td class="col-md-1">` but this makes no difference.

Is there a way of resizing the width with Bootstrap?

This is the HTML:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">1</button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">2<br>ABC</button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">3<br>DEF</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">4<br>GHI</button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">5<br>JKL</button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">6<br>MNO</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">7<br>PQRS</button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">8<br>TUV</button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">9<br>WXYZ</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">&lt;<br></button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">0<br></button></td>
        <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Clr<br></button></td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "with bootstrap"? Like native bootstrap and no custom styles?

Comment: Yes just with Bootstrap 3.0. I haven't used any custom styles yet.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, I provided an alternative below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a width to the table like this (assuming you add `id="phone-table"` to your `<table>`):

```
@media (min-width:767px) {
  #phone-table{
      width:20%;
  }
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
  #phone-table{
      width:40%;
  }
}
```

I used media queries so that the table maintains responsiveness and won't be too large or small on any screen.

### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/4NSPQZnexN)

Comment: So, do I include @media in a custom CSS file that's called after the bootstrap css file?

Comment: Great thanks....and I can play about with the width sizes to get the desired effect?

Comment: Yes, and you can find information on the native bootstrap pixel width break points here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592968/bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-media-queries