# How to Add More Breakpoints to Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please let me know how can I add more Breakpoints to Bootstrap 3?As you know Bootstrap is providing the grid system with 4 predefined as:

```
@screen-xs = 480px
@screen-sm = 768px
@screen-md = 992px
@screen-lg = 1200px
```

I found out it is possible to add more breakpoints to Bootstrap using LESS but unfortunatly I couldnt find any tutorial to figure it out how to do this. For example if I want to add a new breakpoint like

```
@screen-lgB = 1600px
```

can you please let me know how to do that? Thanks

Comment: If you don't already use LESS - and semi advanced -- this won't make any sense. You open up the mixins/grid-framework.less and add it to the .make-grid-columns() mixin just at the top. Then open /mixins/grid.less (NOTICE that this is in the mixins/ and add your grid after // Generate the large columns, then open up the less/grid.less (NOT INSIDE THE MIXINS directory) and add your grid mixin. Then you will need to open up responsive-utilities.less and add your responsive utilities for your new column class like the others.

Comment: Thanks Christina, I have never worked with LESS before, however, I will follow the step you commented to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will solve your problem :

[Bootstrap 3 breakpoints and media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592968/bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-media-queries)

http://alittlecode.com/resolving-breakpoint-conflicts-in-bootstrap-3/

http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/css/

Comment: Hi Mekaeil, Thanks for comment but what I am looking is customizing the core code through LESS. I mean not using Media Queries.