# How to zoom content to screen width

Tags: html, css, zooming, scale, viewport

Consider this example: I manually adjusted the body zoom to 60% in order to make #content div fit horizontally, (The content div must not wrap or scroll and  the content is not restricted to text, it contains more divs, tables, spans, etc. In the example I used the text just to demonstrate the overflow)

```css
body{

  zoom:60%
  
}


#content{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
THIS CONTENT HAS TO FIT HORIZONTALLY ON SCREEN, THIS CONTENT CAN'T WRAP NOR SCROLL BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
</div>
```

How can I zoom it out or scale it down to fit the screen width automatically?
Can you point me to an example or sources?

I've reading about css @viewport and jquery ui scale funcion but I can't make it work.

(Downvotes in 3, 2, 1...)

Comment: similar [How to calculate CSS zoom factor in dependence on screen width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642798/how-to-calculate-css-zoom-factor-in-dependence-on-screen-width)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simpler method: use Javascript to manipulate the CSS scale class:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


var width = document.getElementById('hijo').offsetWidth;
            var height = document.getElementById('hijo').offsetHeight;
            var windowWidth = $(document).outerWidth();
            var windowHeight = $(document).outerHeight();
            var r = 1;
            r = Math.min(windowWidth / width, windowHeight / height)

            $('#hijo').css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + r + ')',
                '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + r + ')',
                '-ms-transform': 'scale(' + r + ')',
                '-o-transform': 'scale(' + r + ')',
                'transform': 'scale(' + r + ')'
            });

});
```

```css
#padre{
   overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
      
  }


#hijo{
  left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible;
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
     transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="padre">
       <div id="hijo">
         THIS CONTENT HAS TO FIT HORIZONTALLY ON SCREEN, THIS CONTENT CAN'T WRAP NOR SCROLL BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried: `#content{font-size:1.2vw;}`. The `vw` unit will adjust to screen width (there is also a `vh` unit that adjusts to screen height). Get the size right and it should always shrink the font to an appropriate size.

*The `vw` unit divides the screen width into 100 units, and assigns size based on desired number of units. Similar to percent, but not reliant on parent.* [See this explanation at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Alternately, explore CSS media queries. They work like this:

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    #content{font-size:8px;}
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    #content{font-size:9px;}
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
    #content{font-size:10px;}
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    #content{font-size:12px;}
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    #content{font-size:14px;}
}



/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
    #content{font-size:14px;}
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    #content{font-size:12px;}
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    #content{font-size:10px;}
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    #content{font-size:9px;}
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    #content{font-size:8px;}
}
```

Resources:

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

[Bootstrap 3 breakpoints and media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592968/bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-media-queries)

https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, the content is not restricted to text, it contains more divs, tables, spans, etc. In the example I used the text just to demonstrate the overflow

Comment: Thanks I used the scale class, your post is useful though, thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm going to use my own hack:

1. Get the rendered width of the element
2. Append a < style > element in the header
3. Get that element you just added
4. Insert the @viewport class with width= renderedwith

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var width = document.getElementById('content').offsetWidth;
      $("head").append('<style type="text/css"></style>');
      var viewPortElement = $("head").children(':last');
      viewPortElement.html('@viewport{width:' + width + 'px}');
    });
```

```css
#content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  THIS CONTENT HAS TO FIT HORIZONTALLY ON SCREEN, THIS CONTENT CAN'T WRAP NOR SCROLL BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
</div>
```

The snippet here doesn't work, the script is getting blocked by this website but it works if you run it in your machine