# How to make image cover full widht

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `HTML`

```html
<div id="book_container" class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" style="border: 1px solid red;">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid green;">
      <div id="leftInside">

        <div class="overlayImageDiv">

          <div id="left_pagenumber"></div>
          <div id="leftNextPage" data-current-left-page>Previous PAGE</div>
          <div id="leftImageData">Here is the image name</div>
          <div id="PreviousPage2" style="background-color:blue; z-index:1">Previous page</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="border: 1px solid blue;" id="coil">
      <img src="http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/5/6/4/1/400x400/ate3660500081564/rw/cuisine-pasta-fileur-angle.jpgg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div id="rightInside">
        <div class="overlayImageDiv">
          <div id="right_pagenumber">
            <div id="rightNextPage" data-current-right-page>NEXT PAGE</div>
            <div id="rightImageData">Here is the image name</div>
            <div id="NextPage">Click Next</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These both divs are side by side well for some reason, I am unable to show them side by side in this snippet. My question is that How I can make the image to be at full height as it should be visible as a coil betweek both pages. Here is how it is being visible now
[image]

Comment: could you add a picture of what it currently looks like since the snippet is wrong?

Comment: @PatrickSchaefer see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to consider.

(1) DIVs not appearing side-by-side in your question because bootstrap is responsive and the breakpoints (where bootstrap auto-switches from, for example, a `col-md-5` to a `col-xs-12`) are wrong for the StackOverflow code area.

[Bootstrap 3 breakpoints and media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592968/bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-media-queries)

https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

(2) Instead of using an `<img>` tag, use the CSS `background-image` or `background` property, and then use `background-position` (either `cover` or `contain`) to force the image to cover a specific part of the containing div. Note that (with CSS) you can specify where the visible window begins/ends (e.g. `center center`).

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

---

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2spajhw9/) displays the result better than the Stack Code Snippet does.

```css
xbody{overflow:hidden;}
.row{height:60px;}
#coilIMG{height:100%;background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/2006-02-04_Metal_spiral.jpg/304px-2006-02-04_Metal_spiral.jpg)center center no-repeat;background-position:contain;}
#coilIMG{overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="book_container" class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="border: 1px solid green;">
      <div id="leftInside">

        <div class="overlayImageDiv">

          <div id="left_pagenumber"></div>
          <div id="leftNextPage" data-current-left-page>Previous PAGE</div>
          <div id="leftImageData">Here is the image name</div>
          <div id="PreviousPage2" style="background-color:blue; z-index:1">Previous page</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="border: 1px solid blue;" id="coilIMG">
      <!--<img src="catalog/view/theme/fastor/image/coils.png" />-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div id="rightInside">
        <div class="overlayImageDiv">
          <div id="right_pagenumber">
            <div id="rightNextPage" data-current-right-page>NEXT PAGE</div>
            <div id="rightImageData">Here is the image name</div>
            <div id="NextPage">Click Next</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .col-xs-5 -->
  </div><!-- .row -->
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div><!-- .container -->
```