# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse in Bigger resolution

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change boostrap 3 navbar to collapse in bigger resolution (now is ~740 px width) and i want to change it to 940 px , how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the Bootstrap source, you can modify the LESS variables (in variables.less) and compile the LESS into CSS yourself.  The variable you're looking for specifically is @screen-sm, which is 768 by default.

A similar post on SO ([Bootstrap 3.0 Media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796505/bootstrap-3-0-media-queries)), mentions using Boostrap's customize option to make changes like this without having to download the source (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics, then scroll down to "Media queries breakpoints"), but I can't actually change the variables within that page, so I think you'll need to use the source and compile to CSS yourself.

Another question on SO worth reading discusses some best practices for changing those variables without getting your copy of the Bootstrap source too far out of sync that it would be difficult to upgrade. The question deals specifically with Bootstrap 2, but I think it's still worth reading.
[Twitter Bootstrap Customization Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451317/twitter-bootstrap-customization-best-practices)

**Edit:** Bootstrap's documentation suggests modifying the @grid-float-breakpoint variable. That would be a more specific change to the responsive settings than modifying @screen-sm. [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)